# Would a square logo/sign be read like a name seal or like a western sign, if the characters lined up?

Tags: names, word-order, sorting-order

Say I had a sign that read 中華料理, but I wanted to fit it into a square for a shop sign, or maybe a t-shirt.
Would it be better to use left-to-right, top-to-bottom:

```
中華
料理
```

or top-to-bottom, right-to-left:

```
料中
理華
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are possible options. For example, [ユニクロ's logo](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&p=%E3%83%A6%E3%83%8B%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%20%E5%BA%97%E8%88%97) and [三国無双's logo](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&p=%E4%B8%89%E5%9B%BD%E7%84%A1%E5%8F%8C%20%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B4) are "western-style" (or "I♡NY-style"), while [眼鏡市場's logo](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&p=%E7%9C%BC%E9%8F%A1%E5%B8%82%E5%A0%B4%20%E5%BA%97%E8%88%97) and [産経新聞's logo](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&p=%E7%94%A3%E7%B5%8C%E6%96%B0%E8%81%9E%20%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B4&aq=-1&oq=) are "hanko-style". Native Japanese speakers often re-read this type of square logo until it makes sense.

In general, if you have accompanying design elements that flow horizontally or vertically, you probably want to make everything consistent. If this 中華料理 is all that will be printed on a shirt, whichever is fine, but IMHO the western-style may be a bit safer unless your design is clearly hanko-like.